# How can I mock up an instance of my main Winform form to test some methods?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Moq (which I am very new too as well as TDD period).  And I wanted to Moq up an instance of my main Winforms form so I could test a few methods on there. Is this possible?  Its constructor takes an object of Assembly().

I was trying the following attempts unsuccessful:

```
var mockMainForm = new Mock<MainForm>();
mockMainForm.Setup(x => x.Assembler).Returns(new Assembly());
return mockMainForm.Object;
```

<strike>But I can't access any properties or methods on this object once it is returned.  Is this possible to do?</strike>

But I get errors that ( failed: System.ArgumentException : Expression is not a method invocation: x => x.Assembler
    at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.ToMethodCall(LambdaExpression expression))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocking using Moq will only mock the interfaces and virtual methods of a class. `Assembler` property needs to be defined as `virtual`.

In any case Mocking a Windows Form is not a good mocking - it has a big bag of WIN32 stuff which make your tests brittle. If you need to unit test and mock a form, create an interface that your form needs to implement and mock that for objects that need to interact with your form.

```
public interface IHasAssembler
{
    Foo Assembler {get; set;}
}

public class MyForm : IHasAssembler
{
     //
}
```

then mock the interface and not the form:

```
Mock<IHasAssembler> myMock = new Mock<IHasAssembler>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used (or, indeed, heard of) Moq, but I am going to guess that `mockMainForm.Object` is of type `Form`, and that you can cast to get at it:

```
object moqObject = MakeMoqOfMyMainForm();
Form mainForm = (Form)moqObject;
```

(If I am wrong, let me know and I will delete this answer)

Comment: New to programming and using Moq and TDD, I can't say that your answer is technically wrong or not, but it doesn't help me with using Moq to accomplish my attempt to use Moq to mock the main form.

Comment: Well, your question was different when I posted my answer. You wanted to access the methods, etc on your form, so I helped you get the Form object. That said, I don't actually know if that's what the `.Object` property contains, since I've never used Moq before.